# Views are not update when it switch to and return from other tab in tabhost

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am working on a tabhost with **2 fragment**,

the first one is a main page, the other is setting page

For the first fragment, there are a image view as well as a listview with imageviews on it

Those images are get from the internet, that is doing some asynctask, then get the link, 
and calling another asynctask to download image and set it as bitmap

I found a problem , when I am at main page, after I finish the asynctask and get the links, I switch to setting page, when I go back main page again, the imageview are not update, only when I go to setting page and go back main page again , it update. How to fix it? thanks

ImageLoader

```
public class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

    private static String TAG = "ImageLoader";
    private InputStream input;
    private ImageView view;
    private String imageURL;
    private String type;
    private MyApp gs;
    private Context ctx;

    public ImageLoader(Activity _ctx,String _type){
        ctx = _ctx;
        gs = (MyApp) _ctx.getApplication();
        type = _type;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            view = (ImageView) params[0];

            //handle Chinese characters in file name
            String[] imgUrlArray = ((String) params[1]).split("/");
            String fileName = imgUrlArray[imgUrlArray.length - 1];
            String newfileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileName,"utf-8");
            imageURL = ((String) params[1]).replace(fileName, newfileName);

            URL url = new URL(imageURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null && view != null) {
            view.setImageBitmap(result);

            if (type.equals("video"))
                gs.setVideoImg(result);
            else if (type.equals("latestPub"))
                gs.setlatestPubImg(result);
            else if (type.equals("book"))
                gs.addBookImgList(result);
            else if (type.equals("poster")) 
                gs.addPosterList(result);
            else if (type.equals("other")) 
                gs.addOtherList(result);

        } else if (type.equals("book")){
            gs.addBookImgList(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        } else if (type.equals("poster")){
            gs.addPosterList(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        } else if (type.equals("other")){
            gs.addOtherList(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your TabActivity class set OnTabChangedListener like this:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
          if (getCurrentActivity() instanceof main) {
                ((yourTabActivity) getCurrentActivity()).yourUpdateMethod();
          }
    }
}
```

and write yourUpdateMethod() in main class to update imaeg with asyncTask.